# How to use if statement and search for last letter in array

Tags: java, arrays, string, if-statement

I need to basically create an if statement that basically says "If the last letter of the string in the array is P, then  blah blah blah, but I do not know the correct way to do this.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public double calculateBonus(String str)            
    {
        double dResult = 0.0;
        double dResult = 0.0;
        String twoLol = str.substring( 0,2);
        for ( int d=0; d<bonusPts.length; d++ ) 
            {
```

Comment: This is not even a full piece of code

Comment: `dResult` twice? where is the so called array? is it `bonusPts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (twoLol.charAt(twoLol.length()-1)=='P'){
   //blah deee blah
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the methods of the String class, there is one called .length() and .charAt(int index), .charAt(int index) returns the character in the index you specify, so if you say yourString.charAt(10) it will give you the character on the tenth position, so is easy to do a comparison

> int   length()
>             Returns the length of this string.
>
> char    charAt(int index)
>             Returns the character at the specified index.

combine those two methods and you can easily get the char you want, from then is easy to do an

```
if(c=='P')
```

c is a char

Answer (score 1):

You can use `charAt()` and `length()` method of String class. Code example below will yield "d"

```
String str = "hello world";
char last = str.charAt(str.length()-1);
System.out.println(last);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bascially, the last character of your string can be found by whateverString.length()-1. 
You can also find it using a loop, but this is faster. 
Now just treat whateverString.lenth()-1 as a character and compare it to 'P' or any other value!